# DateTime parsing works on one machine but crashes on another

Tags: python, datetime, encoding, strftime

I have the following DateTime and string encoding related issue:

I want to parse a date out of the string "Freitag, 03. März 2017". To do that, I use the following lines of code:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_DE")

if re.findall(r"[\w]+, [0-9][0-9]\. [\w]+ [0-9]+", date):
   self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date.strip().encode("utf-8"), '%A, %d. %B %Y').date()

else:
   formattedDate = ', 0'.join(date.split(", ")).encode("utf-8")
   self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(formattedDate.strip(), '%A, %d. %B %Y').date()
```

This works well on my machine (macOS, system language is German), but crashes on the OpenShift instance this code is running on:

```
self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime(formattedDate.strip(), '%A, %d. %B %Y').date()
File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Freitag, 03. M\xc3\xa4rz 2017' does not match format '%A, %d. %B %Y'
```

Comment: Almost sure you've not installed de_DE locale on OpenShift server.

Comment: @felipsmartins Hmm, would that not also break parsing any other German date? The other months work, suggesting this is indeed an encoding issue

Comment: @rodalfus If your server doesn't support UTF-8 encoding, RIP

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try this out, hence cannot tell whether it does anything beyond skirting the issue of setting *locale*, if indeed it does that. But babel does appear to use its own code for handling locale.

```
>>> from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time, get_month_names
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(\d\d)\. ([\w]+) (\d{4})',  "Freitag, 03. März 2017").groups()[1]
'März'
>>> months = [get_month_names(width='wide',context='stand-alone', locale='de_DE')[m] for m in range(1,13)]
>>> months
['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember']
>>> months.index('März')
2
```